# Remove the element from list when the needed tab is empty in R

Tags: r, excel

I have thousands of excel files. first I read the file's name into a list.

The example list looks like this

```
> file.list
[1] 'file1.xlsx'
[2] 'file2.xlsx'
[3] 'file3.xlsx'
...
[1000] 'file1000.xlsx'
```

Each file contain a tab, which name has "Quote" string (the tab's name could be EQuote, E-Quote or EQuote xxx). I need to read this tab and do some steps to clean the datafram. So, I write the following code to clean the dataframe.

```
whole_data <- lappy(file.list, function(file){
   sheet <- readxl::excel_sheet(file)
   quote_sheets <- sheets[grepl('Quote', sheet, ignore.case = FALSE)]
   df <- read-excel(file, sheet = quote_sheets)

   ...the cleaning steps...

   df
})
```

I find that the "Quote" tab in some excel files is empty, so the cleaning step wont work when the tab is empty.

Can you help me find out the file with empty "Quote" tab and remove the file's name from file.list.

For example, if "Quote" tab of file1.xlsx is empty, the code would help me find out and remove it from the list automatically. Then turn the file.list like this:

```
> file.list
[1] 'file2.xlsx'
[2] 'file3.xlsx'
...
[999] 'file1000.xlsx'
```

So, I do not need to check thousands of files manually to see whether this file' "Quote" tab is empty or not.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please check your code, you have mis-matching brackets on line 3 of `whole_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your function to skip those files. Note that I have corrected some typos in your code. If you have multiple  Quote sheets in each file, you need to process them one by one, which is not considered in this code chunk.

**Edits:** considered empty sheet.

```
library(readxl)
file.list = dir(".", pattern = "*.xls")

whole_data <- lappy(file.list, function(file) {
  sheet <- excel_sheets(file)
  quote_sheets <- sheet[grepl('Quote', sheet, ignore.case = FALSE)]
  if (length(quote_sheets) > 0) {
    df <- read_excel(file, sheet = quote_sheets)
    if (nrow(df) > 0) {
      ...the cleaning steps...

      df
    }
  } else
    NA
})
```

Comment: The if function is to check the name of the tab, if the name length >0, so will run the cleaning steps. But in my data files, the "Quote" tab content is empty, not the name is NULL. If the the content of "Quote" is empty, can I still use your code to clean my data?

Comment: In that case, you need to check if the df is empty. Please check my edited code.